# Angular 4 - Share data with directive attribute

Tags: javascript, angular, components, interpolation, directive

I'm trying to make a tooltip directive/component, but everything i tried, i cannot use interpolation in my tooltip to use variables from a repeat.
My home markup looks like this:

```
<md-card class='col-md-3 image-gallery' *ngFor="let advertiser of AdvertiserService.advertisers;let i = index" [@fadeIn]>
    <md-card-content 
    [tooltip]="template" [advertiser]="advertiser">
        //some other markup
    </md-card-content>
</md-card>
```

My tooltip directive looks like this:

```
import { ComponentFactoryResolver, ComponentRef, Directive, ElementRef, 
HostListener, Injector, Output, Input, ReflectiveInjector, Renderer2,     
TemplateRef, Type, ViewContainerRef, ViewRef } from '@angular/core';
import { TooltipComponent } from './tooltip.component';
import { AdvertiserClass } from './../advertiser/advertiser-class';

@Directive({
    selector: '[tooltip]'
})
export class TooltipDirective {
    // We can pass string, template or component
    @Input('tooltip') content: string | TemplateRef<any> | Type<any>;
    @Input('advertiser') advertiser: AdvertiserClass;
    private componentRef: ComponentRef<TooltipComponent>;

    constructor(private element: ElementRef,
        private renderer: Renderer2,
        private injector: Injector,
        private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
        private vcr: ViewContainerRef) {
    }

    @HostListener('mouseenter')
    mouseenter() {
        //console.log(this.advertiser);
        if (this.componentRef) return;
        const factory = 
this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(TooltipComponent);
        const injector = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate([
            {
                provide: 'tooltipConfig',
                useValue: {
                    host: this.element.nativeElement
                }
            }
        ]);
        this.componentRef = this.vcr.createComponent(factory, 0, injector, 
this.generateNgContent());
    }

    generateNgContent() {
        if (typeof this.content === 'string') {
            const element = this.renderer.createText(this.content);
            return [[element]];
        }

        if (this.content instanceof TemplateRef) {
            const viewRef = this.content.createEmbeddedView({});
            return [viewRef.rootNodes];
        }

        // Else it's a component
        const factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(this.content);
        const viewRef = factory.create(this.injector);
        return [[viewRef.location.nativeElement]];
    }

    @HostListener('mouseout')
    mouseout() {
        this.destroy();
    }

    destroy() {
        this.componentRef && this.componentRef.destroy();
        this.componentRef = null;
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.destroy();
    }
}
```

And my tooltip component looks like this:

```
import { Component, Directive, ElementRef, Inject, OnInit, ViewChild, Input         
} from '@angular/core';
import { AdvertiserClass } from './../advertiser/advertiser-class';

@Directive({
    selector: '.tooltip-container'
})
export class TooltipContainerDirective {
}

@Component({
    template: `
    <div class="tooltip-container" [ngStyle]="{top: top}">
        {{advertiser | json}}
    </div>
  `,
    styles: [
        `
      .tooltip-container {
        background-color: black;
        color: #fff;
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 0.5em;
        position: absolute;
      }
    `
    ]
})
export class TooltipComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input('advertiser') advertiser: AdvertiserClass;
    top: string;
    @ViewChild(TooltipContainerDirective, { read: ElementRef }) private 
tooltipContainer;

    constructor( @Inject('tooltipConfig') private config) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        const { top } = this.config.host.getBoundingClientRect();
        const { height } = 
this.tooltipContainer.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect();
        this.top = `${top - height}px`;
    }
}
```

How could i use the {{advertisers}} interpotalion in the code that would works?
I have tried every variant of this, but i couldnt make pass the repeated data to the tooltip components template.

Comment: mmm just two things . .one why did you call tooltip your directive AND ALSO a INPUT PROPERTY? .. then ..have you tried a console.log in the @input change event?

Comment: Yeah, i know shouldn't need both, i just tried out maybe it will work. But yeah, that input console logs thr right data!

Comment: so if it helped you rate my comment ;-)

Answer (score 0):

As is, your tooltip directive knows about the advertiser, but the TooltipComponent, who's data is used to generate the view, does not. What you need to do is pass the advertiser from the directive to the TooltipComponent when the directive creates it. I would probably do that in the 'tooltipconfig' object that you're creating and injecting into the TooltipComponent.

```
    const injector = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate([
        {
            provide: 'tooltipConfig',
            useValue: {
                host: this.element.nativeElement,
                advertiser: this.advertiser
            }
        }
    ]);
```

Then in the ToolTipComponent you can pull that value out of the config object in the constructor to make it available to the template

```
constructor( @Inject('tooltipConfig') private config) {
    this.advertiser = config.advertiser;
}
```

or you could make your config object public in the constructor and bind to `{{config.advertiser}}` in the template.